# How to batch load data with psql with different encodings?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I have a UTF8 database and a UTF8 script to fill tables with data. However I want to run this script with `psql -d instance -U user -f fillTables.sql`. As my system has a Windows CP1252 encoding it looks like psql uses this to parse the file. I found this [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/multibyte.html) and saw these backslash commands, but don't get it working

```
psql \encoding UTF8 -d instance -U user -f fillTables.sql
```

It looks like these are meant for starting psql and entering commands inside the psql console, right? How can I set different encoding for a batch processing of different files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with `export PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8` (in cygwin, there is another syntax for windows), but would accept other answers if they can achieve the same with an option of psql.